# image_picker dose not ask for permission to use gallery and camera

Tags: flutter, dart

image_picker widget does not ask for permission while opening the gallery and camera.
what should I do in order to ask permission though I know that the image_picker package does implicitly ask for permission? but in my case, it didn't. I have tried every solution that I found on the internet .none of them can solve my problem.

pubspec.yml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  # image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
```

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.flutter_application_1">
        <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
             the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
             to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
        -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    
    </manifest>
    
    <!-- <application
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            android:label="xxxxxx"
            android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
            <activity>
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    
            </activity>
    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> -->
```

Comment: Image picker always asks for permission if the user has not set any default permission for the app. Please check your app's permission access.

Comment: app setting shows that 'no permission request' in permission section

Answer (score 1):

use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package:

Try this:

```
void _checkPermission(BuildContext context) async {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statues = await [
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.photos
    ].request();
    PermissionStatus? statusCamera = statues[Permission.camera];
    PermissionStatus? statusStorage = statues[Permission.storage];
    PermissionStatus? statusPhotos = statues[Permission.photos];
    bool isGranted = statusCamera == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        statusStorage == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.granted;
    if (isGranted) {
      //openCameraGallery();
      //_openDialog(context);
    }
    bool isPermanentlyDenied =
        statusCamera == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied ||
            statusStorage == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied ||
            statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied;
    if (isPermanentlyDenied) {
      _showSettingsDialog(context);
    }
  }
```

Comment: still not asking for permission and directly opening the camera and gallery. what should i do now??

Comment: I think permission is granted, delete app in emulator and rebuild again

Comment: but in the phone setting there shows " no permission requested "

Comment: there is two androidmenifest.xml file, which one should i used????/

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<bool> checkAndRequestCameraPermissions() async {
  PermissionStatus permission =
      await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera);
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions =
        await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]);
    return permissions[PermissionGroup.camera] == PermissionStatus.granted;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
Then every call to the image picker has to be wrapped like this to prevent your app from crashing

if (await checkAndRequestCameraPermissions()) {
  File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  // continue with the image ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to ask for gallery permission specifically just ask for camera permission you get the gallery permission automatically and you can use it.

Comment: Aryan I'm using this library. It is not asking for any permission on android when i try to access gallery. I searched on internet and found that this library is not need permission in case of gallery becasue it is not access file directly, it is using the file path and extract the file.
But as per my knowledge, play store reject the app which is not asking for permission and access the gallery.
I'm avoding to implement a permission handler library. So can you please help me what i should do?

Comment: As per my knowledge they will not reject for this reason. I will suggest you to upload the apk to playstore once and if they reject they will specify the reason and then u can work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you add permissions to 'AndroidManifest.xml' file, the permission will be asked automatically when you attempt to use image picker. I used camera and gallery of picker so I put these permissons in 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GALLERY"/>
```

[image]